# IIS Redirect Regex start of string

Tags: regex, iis-7

I am trying to redirect from bsl2 to bsl2 using IIS rewrite

```
http://server/site/bsl2/controllertest.aspx to
http://server/site/bsl3/controllertest.aspx
```

This rule works fine:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="BSL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="bsl2/(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="bls3/{C:1}?test={C:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

but it will also do server/site/otherbsl2/controllertest.aspx

I have tried using ^ to denote the start of the string but it does not work, e.g.

```
<add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(bsl2)/(.*)$" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following regular expression:

```
/bsl2/(.*)$
```

or use word boundary `\b`:

```
\bbsl2/(.*)$
```

Comment: thanks {PATH_INFO} starts with a / that's what I missed (don't know how!)